# Two consecutive numbers removed from first $n$ natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If two consecutive numbers are removed from first  $n$ natural numbers, and the arithmetic mean of remaining numbers is$ \frac {105}{4}$, find $n $.

Let $k $ and $k+1$ be two removed numbers, then we have :

$$ 1+2+3+\cdots +n = 2k+1+\frac{105n-210}{4}. $$ 
Rearranging I got quadratic as  below

$$ 2n^2-103n+206-8k=0.$$

So:
$$ 4n=103 \pm \sqrt {8961+64k}. $$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Who says the two removed numbers are neighbors?

Comment: Do the numbers removed need to be consecutive?

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention they are consecutive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
After getting $2n^2-103n+206=8k$, notice that $1\leq k\leq n-1$
So $$8\leq 2n^2-103n+206\leq 8(n-1)$$
Then you get only few possible values of n.

Comment: Just to add: For the inequality on the left you get that $n\leq 2$ or $n\geq 50$. For the other one you get that $2\leq n \leq 53$. Hence, the values of $n$ that satisfy both inequalities are $50 \leq n\leq 53 $

Comment: So then $n=50$ and the two numbers removed are $7$ and $8$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first n natural number is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.  If the arithmetic mean of these remaining n-2 numbers is 105/4 then their sum is $\frac{(n- 2)105}{4}$.  The difference in sums is the sum of those two missing numbers: $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}- \frac{105(n- 2)}{4}= \frac{2n^2+ 2n- 105n+ 210}{4}= \frac{2n^2- 103n+ 210}{4}$.  Calling the two consecutive numbers that were removed "k" and "k+ 1", then we must have $k+ (k+ 1)= 2k+ 1= \frac{2n^2- 103n+ 210}{4}$.  $2n^2- 102n+ 210= 8k+ 4$ so $2n^2- 102n+ 206- 8k= 0$.  Solve for n using the quadratic formula.

Comment: It should be 103 instead of 102 in the calculation. Also, the OP already reached at this stage and asks how to proceed from this.